# ¿Cómo generar una matriz 2x2 de impresión en pdfmaker?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, pdf, base64, print

tengo una duda sobre como puedo posicionar la impresiónes de mis imagenes, traigo mis imagenes por medio de mi api que estan en base64, pero a la hora de posicionarlas se genera una de bajo de la otra, y necesito que se pongan a la par continuamente, al poder posicionar 4 imagenes con el 25% de width and height cada una.

Mi código

```
axios.get(`../api/eventos/getDiseñoByEvento?eventId=${id}`)

    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data[0]);
        let fondoInvitacion = response.data[0]; //fondoInvitacion es el base64 de la imagen
        // Crear el PDF usando pdfmake
        const pdfMake = window.pdfMake;

        const content = [];
        const pageContent = [];

        for (let i = inicioImpresion; i <= finalImpresion; i++) {
            pageContent.push({
                image: `${fondoInvitacion}`, // Agregar la imagen desde el base64
                width: 300,
                height: 396
            });
        }

        content.push(pageContent);

        const pdfDefinition = {
            content: content,
            pageMargins: [0, 0, 0, 0], // Sin márgenes
        };

        // Generar el PDF y abrir la ventana de impresión
        const pdfDocument = pdfMake.createPdf(pdfDefinition);

        // Abre el diálogo de impresión
        pdfDocument.getBlob((blob) => {
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.display = 'none';
            iframe.src = url;
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.contentWindow.print();
        });

        Swal.fire(`Se generó el PDF de las invitaciones.`);
    }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Ya intente la manera de posiconarlas entre columnas pero no me funcionó,y quiero ver la manera de ver como posicionar 4 imagenes por medio del for, o si hay otra manera.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear una tabla de 2 columnas y n cantidad de filas como una cuadricula, y ahí si podrías ajustar el tamaño de la imagen y la posición.

http://pdfmake.org/playground.html